# How I can insert my picture in my sass file?

Tags: drupal, sass, path, twig

I'm try to insert my picture but I can't :(
Sorry, but I have always the same problem: my TWIG code:

```
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="phone">
  </div>
```

and my SASS code:

```
.phone {
  background: url('phone.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain; /*This scales the image accoding to the div*/
  background-position: center; /*positions the image in the center*/
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```

and my files are always the same too:

- main-menu

  - phone.png
  - menu.scss

I have always the 404 error...

Answer (score 0):

The path defined in `url()` needs to be relative to your compiled `.css` file rather than the `.scss` file.